# How fileinfo takes the path when I do not specify a particular path in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, fileinfo

Here is my code

```
private const string abc="demo.sql";
var fileinfo = new fileInfo(abc);
```

I want to know how fileInfo will read the path, I mean directory path when I do not specify any path for .sql file. I have placed sql file in some other folder in c# project, wanted to know how I can read the path of this folder

Comment: It will use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will assume the path is the executing directory of where the application is run from..

The variable `fileinfo` would have the following properties and values, if the executing directory of your application was `C:\Program Files(x86)\LINQPad5`

[image]

You'll notice that the `Exists` property is `False`, because there is no file called `demo.sql` in the aforementioned directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helped me a lot

Comment: You're welcome, if I've solved your problem, could you choose this answer as the solution to the question please.